# Is this parametrization identifiable?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, parameterization

So I have this problem which I'm unsure of my answer. Any tip on how to treat it differently is more than welcome.

> X and Y are independent $\mathcal{N}(\mathcal{\mu_1},\sigma^2)$ and
>   $\mathcal{N}(\mathcal{\mu_2},\sigma^2)$, $\theta=(\mu_1,\mu_2)$ and
>   observe $Y-X$
>
> Is this parametrization identifiable?

---

I proceded as the following:
Set $W= Y-X$; $\mu_0=\mu_2-\mu_1$ ; $\sigma_0^2=2\sigma^2$

I did find a pdf for $|W|$ to be :
 $$\mathcal{p}_{|W|}(w)= \frac{1}{\sigma_0 \sqrt{2\pi}}exp\{-\frac{w^2+\mu_0^2}{2\sigma_0^2}\}(exp(\frac{w\mu_0}{\sigma_0^2}))+(exp(\frac{w\mu_0}{\sigma_0^2}))$$

Now, setting the $\mu_0'=\mu_0-\Delta$, for real $\Delta$

and replacing $\mu_0$ in my equation would definitely yield a different pdf hence the parametrization is identifiable since with $\theta_1 \neq \theta_2 \Rightarrow P_{\theta_1} \neq P_{\theta_2}$

Comment: You can't tell $\mu_1=3,\mu_2=2$ from $\mu_1=5,\mu_2=4$, since they give the same $\mu_2-\mu_1$. You can identify the mean of $W$ but as I read it, the question is asking about identifiability of the parameters for $X$ and $Y$

Comment: I thought they wanted to observe the difference and not each of them. You have a point since the question specify the parameter.

Comment: From your comment, the parametrization is not identifiable then.

Comment: If you don't mind me asking what it is really to have a parametrization that is not identifiable in the real world. I've been googling and  asked questions in class but got no luck

Comment: Not sure what "in the real world" is intended to cover, but certainly it's possible for people to try to fit models that are unidentifiable. It happens any time there's more than one value of some vector of parameters that would produce the same distribution of the data. As for googling it .... I can't imagine what you tried, but my first search turned up the relevant Wikipedia article  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identifiability as the first hit; that in turn links to this simpler article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parameter_identification_problem

Comment: You may find some of the hits on our site with [this search](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22not+identifiable%22) useful. In particular, this post may be useful to you: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/20608/what-is-model-identifiability

Comment: As for a practical example of non-identifiability in models that comes up a lot in practice, consider: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/265898/why-is-a-normal-mixture-model-not-identifiable-and-why-does-it-matter

Comment: This truly is of great help. Your comments are a gold mine for me. Thank you Glen_b. I'll be back with better questions !